# ways to include many header files

Tags: c

Recently I came across code which handled header files this way.
There would be one header file called say `global.h`
This `global.h` would include some other header files, e.g.,

```
#include "settings.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "somelibrary.h"
#include "someOtherlibrary.h"
...
```

Now, whenever some file wanted to include say `somelibrary.h`, instead of writing
`#include somelibrary.h` it would just include `global.h`.
So each source file in the project just had: `#include "global.h"`

Is this common way to avoid writing many includes in each source file? what are other benefits

ps. extra: it would be nice if someone could explain why this works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a commonly used *bad* practice. If you use a global.h, you create a tight coupling between that file and every module in the project, which in turn creates a tight coupling between every single module of your project.

That is very bad OO design! You want each module to be autonomous and only depend on other modules that are actually crucial for its own functionality. Further more, you will always want to design modules so that they can be used in several projects.

For example, if I want to use your generic math library module, which you have already developed for a particular project, then why on earth would you force me to include every other unrelated file from that project as well?

As for "avoid writing many includes in each source file"... It is completely beyond me how having to write 5-10 very short lines of text at the top of a file can be a major obstacle to a programmer. Apparently there are plenty of people who find that to be such an obstacle, that they decide to *change the whole program design* because of it. If you don't like typing on the keyboard, then maybe don't go for a programmer career.

Comment: maybe you could add few lines why this approach(the one I outlined) works

Comment: @user2568508 It works because properly written header files have header guards, `#ifndef MYHEADER_H` and so on. So that particular library is only linked once, the first time it is found. Also, the linker only includes (or should only include) functions that are used by the program. If you `#include <stdio.h>" only to use printf, then nothing else in stdio.h but that function will get linked to your program.

Comment: Something tells me that this answer comes from a real world experience :)

Comment: @Lundin: ok I was expecting more elaboration along the lines that it seems this kind of "proxy" include is also fine in c right? e.g., when I include one file which includes other file (and thus get functionality from the latter file)

Comment: @user2568508 It is fine if you include files that your module needs. If you are writing a program that draws geometrical figures, it is fine for that module to include trigonometry.h, and it is fine for trigonometry.h in turn to include pi.h which only contains the constant 3.14. But it isn't fine for pi.h to include the whole graphics library, that doesn't make sense. Getting your dependencies straight is very important in program design. Luckily, common sense and good program design go hand-in-hand.

Answer (score 4):

Only benefit is the ease of including.

Downside is that everytime you make change to a header file, you have to re-compile **everything**. For any larger project this is a big deal.

It also makes removing or changing existing modules a pain, because you cannot do simple search for specific include to have an overview of where it is used.

Just don't do it.

**Edit:**

To clarify: It's OK to group headers in one if they are needed to do X. However I have rarely need to do this in practice; writing `#include "xxxxx.x"` is not too hard.

It's not OK to have one header with everything in it for entire application which does X, Y and Z.

Comment: So it is mainly about ease of use? It doesn't solve some specific problem right?

Comment: It can be useful if you group your includes together. For example if you have `matrix.h` which includes `m_vector.h`, `m_matrix.h`, `m_multiplication.h` and such it would be very convenient.

Comment: @user2568508 If one specific library groups it's headers to one it is not a problem. But if your application has one big massive header, it is more problem than it is worth.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: This answer refers to the case when the include files come from different projects**

As long as the include files are referring to *other* projects or libraries (as opposed to header files of the same project), I'd call it a reasonable way of straightening out the includes. With the "precompiled header" support from Microsoft Compilers, there's even a big performance benefit in doing so. It also ensures you're always including the headers in the same order, because this could sometimes lead to strange errors if two includes internally depend on each other.

The preferred way of creating so called "standard include headers" for MSVC is to have one file (usually named "stdafx.h"), which contains the header files of all the libraries the project is going to use, namely windows.h, math.h, io.h or string. With the correct compiler settings, all the includes that are mentioned in "stdafx.h" are only processed once for the whole project. Since these files hardly ever change, the fact that changing them requires rebuilding the whole project is not an issue. The line with `#include "stdafx.h"` *must* be the first in every c or cpp file, though. ASFAIK, gcc has no equivalent for this.

Comment: I think it was referring mainly to header files of same project, but I'd need to double check

Comment: The names in your example made me think otherwise. But (see also the other answer) I agree that the two cases should be looked at separately.

Comment: ok so it is also one way to include many headers just I hadn't seen this approach in standard text. Btw. Maybe if you or other answerer could elaborate why this approach works (e.g., if it is eligible approach etc. then I'd accept the answer)